# Setting CSS style of a class based on focus of another

Tags: css

Is it possible to change the style of a different class (TicCell) based on FOCUS of another (RadioTic)

```
.
.
<td>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="TicCell"><input type="checkbox" class="RadioTic" name="some_field"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
.
.
```

Ive got this in my head.

```
.RadioTic:focus{
  .TicCell{
  background: #FCFFBA;
  border: 2px solid #FCFFBA; 
  }
}
```

Comment: `less` css might help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems the answer is NO, but here is some JQuery that does the trick.

```
        $('.RadioTic').focus(function() {
            $('.TicCell').css('background-color', '#FCFFBA');
            $('.TicCell').css('border', '2px solid #e2e5a7');
        });
        $('.RadioTic').blur(function() {
          $('.TicCell').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
          $('.TicCell').css('border', 'none');
        });
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the case.  It is easy to change a class on a child style by focus-ing/hovering on a parent/ancestor element, but the reverse can't be done with CSS.  You need JavaScript/jQuery.  This question comes up maybe 1-2 times per week on SO.  The jQuery solution is very acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I dont understand what do you mean by focus. Anyway why not do it like this:

**w/o focus**

```
 .RadioTic,
    .TicCell{
      background: #FCFFBA;
      border: 2px solid #FCFFBA; 
    }
```

or **w/ focus**

```
.RadioTic:focus,
.TicCell{
  background: #FCFFBA;
  border: 2px solid #FCFFBA; 
}
```

two class with the same design.

Comment: Tried it, but it did not work. The "focus" on you listed sets the style for the "TicCell" class regardless of the tick box having focus or not. Thanks anyway.